# How to properly initialize plugins with new vim 8 packages feature?

Tags: plugin-system, packages

I'm using denite plugin and I have some intialization for it.

```
call denite#custom#source(
    \ 'file_rec', 'matchers', ['matcher_fuzzy', 'matcher_project_files'])
call denite#custom#var('file_rec/git', 'command', ['git', 'ls-files', '-co', '--exclude-standard'])
```

Since I moved from external package manager into vim packages I moved this into a function that is executed inside `VimEnter` autocmd. But now I want to open denite prompt when no files have been passed to vim as arguments.

```
au VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | exe ":Denite `finddir('.git', ';') != '' ? 'file_rec/git' : 'file_rec'`"
```

Which is quite easy, but the problem is that at this point vim still doesn't know anything about my custom 'file_rec/git' command.

I've tried to place initialization into `~/.vim/after/plugin/denite.vim`, but that doesn't help. Vim is saying that he basically doesn't know what denite is at this point.

Comment: Try to run `:scriptnames` to see which scripts are loaded in which order.

Comment: @laktak Well, obviously ~/.vim/after/plugin/denite.vim is loaded before denite plugin, and `scriptnames` confirmed that. But now what?

Comment: well it's good to see that your scripts are loaded but are you sure that `~/.vim/after/plugin/denite.vim` is loaded before the plugin? If yes then that's the problem.

Comment: @laktak Yes, I'm sure and obviously that's the problem. But is it supposed to be that way or not?

Answer (score 1):

[`:help startup`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#startup) describes what Vim does on startup. I won't repeat the full details here, but you're correct that packages are loaded right after the initialization files (vimrc etc.) However, you can use the [`:packloadall`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Apackloadall) to do this earlier if desired.

That being said, the `VimEnter` autocmd is run as the last step, and packages should have been loaded at this point, so that should work. Your autocommand does look funky though:

```
au VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | exe ":Denite `finddir('.git', ';') != '' ? 'file_rec/git' : 'file_rec'`"
```

- Why is there no `endif`? That seems like an error.
- What are those `` ` ``s? Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I've actually already done this another way, but ` stuff is from denite docs.

Comment: You're still missing an `endif`, though @user1685095

Comment: Yeah, it probably is, but I can't find out, because I've came up with different solution. As to `packloadall`, it's obviously so, but I wouldn't want to do things that vim is already doing automatically manually just because I don't like the order in which it does so. I also thought about making `denite` optional and load it explicitly in vimrc, but this is... wrong let's say. Customizing particular plugin after it is actually initialized is what should be possible.